# Add element to specific index in javascript immutable way

Tags: javascript

I know how to add element at specific index in javascript.

`array.splice(a, b, c)`

However I want an immutable way for this such as:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

arr2 = arr.specialSplice(2, 0, 'a')

// arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
// arr2 = [1,2,'a',3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr2 = [...arr.slice(0,idx), yourNewVal, ...arr.slice(idx)]
```